# Unable to set a dynamic value to predefined object in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to store a dynamic id every time in the array of object format

Suppose I have 3 ids one is
`id = 250` and the second one is `id = 650` and the third one is `id = 850`

and

I want to store it like

```js
[
{
 id:250,
 how_many_times = 1
},
{
 id:650,
 how_many_times = 2
},
{
 id:850,
 how_many_times = 1
}
]
```

But when I tried to set the id it's showing me this error

`Property 'id' does not exist on type '{ id: string; }[]'`

I have tried the following lines of code

first I created an array like this

```js
popUpShowData = [
    {
      id : '',
      how_many_times:0
    }
 ];
```

then I tried to set the value like this

```js
getPopup(dynamicId) {
   this.popUpShowData.id = dynamicId;
   this.popUpShowData.how_many_times = 1;
}
```

but getting this error

`Property 'id' does not exist on type '{ id: string; }[]'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`popUpShowData` is an array, so you have to set the `id` property to one of its items, **not** on it directy:

```js
this.popUpShowData[0].id = dynamicId;
this.popUpShowData[0].how_many_times = 1;
```

---

In general, you should in addition pass the `index` of the item to the function, so you would know which item to update:

```js
getPopup(index, dynamicId) {
  this.popUpShowData[index].id = dynamicId;
  this.popUpShowData[index].how_many_times = 1;
}
```